# uploading file never finishes at p:fileUpload

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces, upload

I am using `p:fileUpload` in the advanced mode. File Uploading never finishes when I try to upload a file. Even if the files are very small, it keeps uploading all the time. In the uploading progress bar, it shows that it is still uploading even the files are very very small. Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Frontend:

```jsf
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <p:panel header="HASH RAPOR AL PARAMETRELERİ">
            <p:panelGrid columns="4">
            Başlangıç  2 : <p:calendar value="#{hashRaporBean.basTarih}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />  Bitiş : <p:calendar value="#{hashRaporBean.bitTarih}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 415px">
                <h:outputText value="veya" style="center" />
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 415px">
                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{hashRaporBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" label="Dosya Seç.." uploadLabel="Dosyayı Yükle" cancelLabel="İptal"
                    dragDropSupport="false" update="messages" sizeLimit="10000000" fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx|XLS|XLSX)$/" 
                    auto="true" ajax="false"/>
                <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" sticky="false" life="3000"/>
                <p:commandButton id="taslakFaturaSorgula" value="Hash Degerleri Al" actionListener="#{hashRaporBean.hashRaporAl(loginBean.satici.SupplierIDVKN)}" 
                style="text-align:center;" widgetVar="startButton1" onclick="start()" oncomplete="cancel()"/>
                <p:progressBar id="progressBarClient" widgetVar="pbClient" style="width:300px"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Does the network tab in the browser developer tool actually show an upload is still going on? Or is it finished and does the progressbar just not disappear? And why the `ajax="false" on the upload tag?

Comment: yes Kukeltje upload tab still show upload is still going on and it never finishes. It does not disappear. It gets into a forever uploading loop and it never finishes